# RDD[Array[String]] to Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am new to Spark and Hive and my goal is to load a delimited(lets say csv) to Hive table. After a bit of reading I found out that the path to load the data into Hive is `csv->dataframe->Hive`.(Please correct me if I am wrong).

```
CSV:
1,Alex,70000,Columbus
2,Ryan,80000,New York
3,Johny,90000,Banglore
4,Cook, 65000,Glasgow
5,Starc, 70000,Aus
```

I read the csv file be using below command:

```
val csv =sc.textFile("employee_data.txt").map(line => line.split(",").map(elem => elem.trim))
csv: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[29] at map at <console>:39
```

Now I am trying to convert this RDD to Dataframe and using below code:

```
scala> val df = csv.map { case Array(s0, s1, s2, s3) => employee(s0, s1, s2, s3) }.toDF()
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [eid: string, name: string, salary: string, destination: string]
```

employee is a case class and I am using it as a schema definition.

```
case class employee(eid: String, name: String, salary: String, destination: String)
```

However when I do `df.show` I am getting below error:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 10.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   0.3 in stage 10.0 (TID 22, user.hostname): scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@88ba3cb (of class
>   [Ljava.lang.String;)

I was expecting a dataframe as a output. I know why I might be getting this error because the values in RDD are stored in `Ljava.lang.String;@88ba3cb` format and I need to use `mkString` to get the actual values but I am not able to find how to do it. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Maybe you can share with us how your `employee` is defined?

Comment: opps sorry, employee is a case class `case class employee(eid: String, name: String, salary: String, destination: String)`

Comment: You are parsing everything as `String` so your `eid: Int` won't work

Comment: What version of spark?

Comment: Spark version: `1.5.0-cdh5.5.1` I tried changing it to String as well but still got the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you fix your case class then it should work:

```
scala> case class employee(eid: String, name: String, salary: String, destination: String)
defined class employee

scala> val txtRDD = sc.textFile("data.txt").map(line => line.split(",").map(_.trim))
txtRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[30] at map at <console>:24

scala> txtRDD.map{case Array(s0, s1, s2, s3) => employee(s0, s1, s2, s3)}.toDF.show
+---+-----+------+-----------+
|eid| name|salary|destination|
+---+-----+------+-----------+
|  1| Alex| 70000|   Columbus|
|  2| Ryan| 80000|   New York|
|  3|Johny| 90000|   Banglore|
|  4| Cook| 65000|    Glasgow|
|  5|Starc| 70000|        Aus|
+---+-----+------+-----------+
```

Otherwise you could convert the `String` to an `Int`:

```
scala> case class employee(eid: Int, name: String, salary: String, destination: String)
defined class employee

scala> val df = txtRDD.map{case Array(s0, s1, s2, s3) => employee(s0.toInt, s1, s2, s3)}.toDF
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [eid: int, name: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> df.show
+---+-----+------+-----------+
|eid| name|salary|destination|
+---+-----+------+-----------+
|  1| Alex| 70000|   Columbus|
|  2| Ryan| 80000|   New York|
|  3|Johny| 90000|   Banglore|
|  4| Cook| 65000|    Glasgow|
|  5|Starc| 70000|        Aus|
+---+-----+------+-----------+
```

However the best solution would be to use [`spark-csv`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) (which would treat the salary as an `Int` as well).

Also note that the error was thrown when you ran `df.show` because everything was being lazily evaluated up until that point. `df.show` is an action which will cause all of the queued transformations to execute (see [this article](http://www.edupristine.com/blog/apache-spark-rdd-transformations-actions) for more).

Comment: Thanks @evan058 for your reply. I tried your solution however I still get the same error.
     `scala> case class employee(eid: String, name: String, salary: String, destination: String)
defined class employee`

    `scala> val csv =sc.textFile("employee_data.txt").map(line => line.split(",").map(elem => elem.trim))
csv: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[19] at map at <console>:31`

    `scala> val df=csv.map{case Array(s0, s1, s2, s3) => employee(s0, s1, s2, s3)}.toDF()
df:..spark.sql.DataFrame=[eid: string, name: string, salary: string, destination: string`

Comment: `scala> df.show`    

`16/12/30 15:37:25 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 11, hostname): scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@3297e00f (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)
        at $line46.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:35)
        at $line46.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:35)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)`

Comment: @Novice try running `csv.foreach{println}`. What does that look like?

Comment: I just ran it but it didn't printed anything.
`scala> csv.foreach{println}`
  empty line  
`scala>`

Comment: Nothing? are you sure your text file is being loaded correctly?

Comment: Try `sc.textFile("employee_data.txt").foreach{println}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131930/discussion-between-novice-and-evan058).

Answer (score 2):

Use map on array elements, not on array:

```
val csv = sc.textFile("employee_data.txt")
    .map(line => line
                     .split(",")
                     .map(e => e.map(_.trim))
     )
val df = csv.map { case Array(s0, s1, s2, s3) => employee(s0, s1, s2, s3) }.toDF()
```

But, why you are reading CSV and then converting RDD to DF? Spark 1.5 already can read CSV via [`spark-csv`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) package:

```
val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true") 
    .option("inferSchema", "true") 
    .option("delimiter", ";") 
    .load("employee_data.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks Gaweda for you reply. I can you use but I have a requirement where I can get file with other delimiters than comma. So I cannot use `spark-csv`

Comment: @Novice there is parameter `delimiter` - you can set it to `;` or some other

Comment: Oh I was not aware about that. Thanks let me search more on it.

Comment: In the `.load(...)` you mention `employee_data.txt`. What if instead of txt file you had a RDD?

Answer (score 1):

As you said in your comment, your case class employee, which should be named `Employee`, receives an `Int` as first argument of its constructor, but you are passing a `String`. Thus, you should convert it to an `Int` before instantiating  or modify your case defining `eid` as a `String`.